# Identity verification via email and/or SMS

Tags: lightning, sms, identity

We have a lightning application on our client website. The dealer guest site profile users i.e., unauthorized users who are not part of the org after filling some of the details we wanted to give them option to have a 2 factor authentication like confirm email and a OTP via sms to proceed to the further form/application. So they can get back to their application and resume their work instead starting over again. Are there any app exchange apps which does this?

Answer (score 0):

This is supported [out of the box](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activating_computer.htm&type=5):

> **SMS Text Message**
>
> If you have a verified mobile number associated with
>   your account, you receive a verification code in a text message sent
>   to your phone. If you don’t have a verified mobile number, you’re
>   prompted to register one when you log in to Salesforce. Registering
>   your mobile phone number verifies it and enables this method when
>   you’re challenged in the future. If your mobile number changes,
>   contact your Salesforce admin.
>
> **Email**
>
> Salesforce sends a verification code in an email to the address
>   associated with your account. The code expires after 24 hours.

The out of the box verification via SMS is a licensed (paid) add-on, it uses Twilio underneath the hood. Most scenarios involving identity verification with anything other than username/password require you to write custom code. Here's an [example](https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/PhoneVerificationLabapp) by Salesforce Labs that shows how to use Twilio Authy in a Lightning Flow for identity verification.